# JQuery smooth scrolling misbehaves on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have a page where some `a` elements which are in a div which is `position: fixed`. Clicking these `a` elements I've intended the windows to scroll smoothly to another `a` element with a corresponding `name` attribute.

The setup is quite simple, it goes like this:

```
<a href="#bluefield"><img src="someimage.png"></a> <!--anchor tag to click -->
<a name="bluefield"></a>
```

And I have this as a jQuery script running:

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
```

});

Now, the code works, and smooth scrolling is happening, but whenever I click let's say anchor A, and then it scrolls down to the right anchor tag with the corresponding `name` attribute, once I click that anchor A again it scrolls back to the top.

What's more is that when I click anchor A and get to the right position, and then I click anchor B, the window scrolls to the top, but with the apparent offset from anchor A to B.

So let's say I clicked on the "Bluefields" link and got to the Bluefields section, and 500px below that is the Greenfields section. Now, when I click on the "Greenfields" link while viewing the Bluefields section, the window scrolls back to the top but has a 500px offset from the top.

I am desperate to find the answer to this because it's driving me insane.

Here, I've provided a JSFiddle for it that replicates exactly the behaviour I'm talking about

https://jsfiddle.net/worldwarotter/es6trw97/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the page is scrolling down, you need to include the `scrollTop` position of the page ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/es6trw97/1/))

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('html , body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $('[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]').offset().top + $(window).scrollTop()
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

I also included a `.stop()` to stop the animation if someone rapidly clicks on the links.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been making me frustrated every time!